# Passed or Set the ActivatedRoute ID to the Firebase WHERE method

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**Situation:**

A user can click a button to view a specific page. My component tries to get the current ID (e.g. http://localhost:8100/home/ID) to that page and that process is successfully done.

**Problem:**

Now my problem is to pass that ID value to my service.ts and in my WHERE method of Firebase. Unfortunately my `this.orgId` is undefined and Firebase throws an error.

Firebase Error:
`FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Function Query.where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined`

The main purpose of the WHERE method is to filter the posts made by the user.

**Codes Snippet:**

**post.service.ts**

```
orgId: string; //Unfortunately this is undefined

  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
    ) {

    this.postCol = this.afs.collection('post', ref => ref.orderBy("createdAt", "desc"));

    //I want to pass it in WHERE method but Firebase throws error because no valid value is 
    //detected
    this.postCol = this.afs.collection('post', ref => ref.where("postOrgId", "==", this.orgId));
    
    this.posts = this.postCol.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(action => {
        return action.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Post;
          data.postId = a.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        })
      })
    );
   }//

  getOrgId(idParameter) {
   this.orgId = idParameter;
  }

  getPosts() {
     return this.posts;
  }
```

**component.page.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {

    //To read the current page ID
    this.orgId = this.activateRoute.snapshot.params['orgID'];

    //It will print the ID in the URL
    //Example: http://localhost:8100/home/ct28yduVIoFUyuiDDwTi
    //It will print "ct28yduVIoFUyuiDDwTi"
    console.log(this.orgId);

    //This is where I passed the ID to service.ts
    this.postService.getOrgId(this.orgId);


    this.orgSub = this.postService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
    });

  }
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.orgId)` and show what it looks like?

Comment: It will print the ID in the URL. Like example http://localhost:8100/home/ct28yduVIoFUyuiDDwTi it will print "ct28yduVIoFUyuiDDwTi" in the console.